# Origine de l'expression « si jamais » ?

Tags: étymologie, expressions-idiomatiques, conditions

Je n'arrive pas trouver l’étymologie de cette expression. Je comprends son utilisation comme un synonyme de « au cas où », mais d'où vient cette tournure étrange ?

Exemple :

> Si jamais tu te le demandes, les cuillères sont dans le tiroir de droite.

Souvent raccourci en :

> Si jamais, les cuillères sont dans le tiroir de droite.

Comment: La phrase  "Si jamais, les cuillères sont dans le tiroir de droite" est incorrecte, son auteur est probablement un étranger qui ne maîtrise pas très bien le français ?

Comment: C'est du langage parlé parfaitement correct en Suisse. En revanche, « *(…) son auteur est probablement un étranger qui ne maîtrise pas très bien le français ?* » n'est pas une question et ne devrait donc pas se terminer par un point interrogation. ;-)

Comment: À mon avis, *if ever you look for the spoons...*/*if you ever wonder where the spoons are...* sont les tournures équivalentes en anglais.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

À l'origine, *jamais* signifie « il existe un moment où ceci est vrai ». Comme d'autres adverbes et pronoms tels que *pas*, *personne*, *aucun*, etc., il n'a guère survécu que dans des constructions négatives, et en français moderne il exprime à lui seul une négation dans la plupart des contextes (« je l'ai jamais vu » (familier) = « je **ne** l'ai jamais vu » (soutenu)). Dans certains contextes, *jamais* a conservé son sens sans négation. Ainsi *si jamais* signifie « s'il existe un moment où ceci est vrai », « si le cas se produit un jour ». En fait, dans ce sens, *jamais* n'est guère plus qu'un intensif pour *si*.

[cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7661/5) a donné des exemples d'utilisation de « si … jamais … » dans un sens un peu différent, et aujourd'hui rare, dans lequel *si* est utilisé pour une condition dont le locuteur affirme la véracité. Le mot *jamais* y renforce la rareté de la circonstance. En français moderne, on retrouve ce sens de *si* dans des phrases telles que « s'il y a bien un légume que je n'aime pas, ce sont les épinards ».

Étymologiquement, *jamais* vient de l'ancien français *[ja](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ja#Ancien_fran.C3.A7ais)*  *[mais](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mais#Ancien_fran.C3.A7ais)*. *Ja* signifie « à ce moment là » (on le retrouve dans *déjà* : à ce moment là ou avant). Dans une phrase négative, il prend la signification de « à ce moment là ou après » : .
Renforcé par *mais* (« d'avantage »), « *ne … ja … mais* » signifie « pas à ce moment là ni avant ni après ».

Je ne connais pas l'expression « si jamais » toute seule, elle ne fait pas partie de mon idiolecte (alors qu'il m'arrive d'utiliser « au cas où » comme raccourci de « au cas où cela se produirait »).

Comment: Pourriez-vous expliciter le **à** dans : *en français moderne il = [ jamais ] exprime **à lui seul** une négation dans la plupart des contextes* ? Pourquoi pas *en français moderne il = [ jamais ] exprime **lui seul** une négation dans la plupart des contextes*

Comment: @LePressentiment C'est une expression figée. Voir le TLF : [seul](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/seul) I.C.1.b. L'adjectif *seul* tout court pourrait avoir le même sens, mais il serait ici ambigu (il pourrait signifier « seulement lorsqu'il est seul », alors que « à lui seul » signifie « y compris lorsqu'il est seul » ou plutôt « intrinsèquement », « par lui-même »).

Answer (score 4):

La première définition du petit Robert :

> adverbe de temps - XI<sup>o</sup>  ; de *ja*, lat. *jam* "déjà", et *mais*, lat. *magis* "plus" *jamais* (sens positif) :
>
> - En un temps quelconque, un jour (passé ou futur)
> - …
> - avec si : au cas où.

Exemples tirés *[du Littré](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/)*, où il est difficile, sinon impossible de remplacer *si jamais* par *au cas où* :

> ♦ Parmi les difficultés que ses intérêts [du prince de Condé]
>   apportaient au traité des Pyrénées, écoutez quels furent ses ordres,
>   et voyez *si jamais* un particulier traita si noblement ses intérêts,
>   BOSSUET, *Louis de Bourbon*. 
> ♦ *Si jamais* l'on peut dire que la
>   voie du chrétien est étroite, c'est, messieurs, durant les
>   persécutions, BOSSUET, *Reine d'Anglet*.
> ♦ *S*'il y eut *jamais*
>   une conjoncture où il fallut montrer de la prudence, ce fut
>   lorsque…, BOSSUET, *Le Tellier*.
> ♦ *Si jamais* il parut un homme
>   extraordinaire…, c'est dans ces rapides moments d'où dépendent les
>   victoires, BOSSUET, *Louis de Bourbon*.

Tous ces exemples fonctionnent avec *si un jour*, ce qui nous renvoie à l’étymologie de *jamais*.

Une certitude : *si jamais* ne concerne jamais l'instant présent, et l'on peut comprendre *jour* par heure, moment (passé ou futur) :

> Si jamais tu fais une bêtise, tu vas voir tout à l'heure…
>   Au cas où tu ferais une bêtise, la sanction est …

- *si … jamais* (un autre jour) : condition liée au temps
- *au cas … où* (dans ce cas là) : condition liée au lieu, à l'espace ou à un objet centre d'intérêt du cas cité.

Answer (score 1):

"***Jamais***", comme "**pas**" ,"***point***" et "***rien***", désigne étymologiquement un **minimum**: "***jamais***" signifie "*un seul instant*" ou "*une seule fois*" ou "*le plus court instant*", "***pas***" signifie "*la plus petite distance*", "***point***" signifie "*la plus petite surface*" et "***rien***" signifie "*la plus petite chose*".

Cela étant admis, on comprend alors pourquoi "jamais", "pas", "point"  et "rien" nécessitent la négation "ne" pour désigner l'absence de temps, de distance, de surface ou de volume: "ne..jamais" signifie "pas même un seul instant", donc "nul instant".

C'est un cas très intéressant, car il montre le glissement qui s'est produit dans la pensée moderne dans la conception de l'opposition entre l'immense et le minuscule, entre le tout et l'insignifiant: Dans la pensée classique, "tout" s'oppose à "un", tandis que dans la pensée moderne, "tout" s'oppose à "zéro", d'où une dégradation du langage telle que beaucoup ne savent plus distinguer "*jamais*" et "*ne...jamais*":

Car si l'on ne perd pas de vue son véritable sens, on comprend que "***jamais***" **peut être employé sans la négation** pour exprimer un moment unique:

***C'est la plus belle femme que j'aie jamais vue***

Ce qui signifie: *Il y a **un seul instant** où j'ai vu une femme aussi belle*. (ici, écrire "que je n'aie jamais vue" constituerait une faute grave, car la phrase n'aurait pas de sens).

Par contre, dans la phrase suivante:

***Je ne sucre jamais mon café***

la négation donne le sens de "aucun instant". Pour les anglophones, on peut expliquer cela en disant que le sens premier de "*jamais*" est "*ever*" et non "*never*" : "*never*" est exprimé par "*ne jamais*".

En considérant ce qui précède, la compréhension de "***si jamais***" ne présente aucun problème:

***"Si jamais tu recommences, tu auras affaire à moi".*** signifie "**si une seule fois tu recommences**..." il n'y donc là aucun mystère.

Answer (score 0):

Et que penser de l'expression *si jamais* dans une phrase comme :

> J'ai une calculette à vous donner si jamais...

(adressé à quelqu'un qui se plaint d'avoir perdu la sienne) ?

Pour moi, cela signifie forcément

> si jamais ... vous la voulez,
> si jamais ... vous ne retrouvez pas la vôtre,
> si jamais... vous en avez besoin...".

Je veux dire que ce qui suit concerne forcément la décision de la personne à qui on s'adresse. En tous cas me semble-t-il. Usage relativement récent (quelques années) selon moi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21978)