# Pourquoi « le tiroir DE droite » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, noms

> Si jamais tu te le demandes, les cuillères sont dans le **tiroir de droite**. [Source](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7659/origine-de-lexpression-si-jamais)

Je suis conscient que « droite » est un nom féminin. Pourquoi « NOM de droite » et non pas :

- NOM à droite
- NOM à la droite
- NOM sur droite
- NOM sur la droite
- NOM vers droite
- NOM vers la droite
- NOM droit (nm) ou NOM (nf) droite  ?

Quelles sont les différences et similarités entre chacune des 7 phrases ? Elles m’apparaissent valables au moyen de http://www.wordreference.com/fren/forumtitles/droite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*De* est à ma connaissance l'unique préposition qui peut se combiner avec *droite*, *gauche*, *en bas* ou *en haut*, sans article, pour introduire un complément de nom. On peut former un complément adverbial qui indique un lieu (*rouler à gauche*), une direction (*tourner à gauche*, *se diriger vers la gauche*) ou une tendance (*virer sur la gauche*) avec d'autres prépositions, mais il complète alors le verbe ou la phrase, pas le nom directement.

Pourquoi ? Dans toute langue, il y a un certain nombre de constructions qui sont purement conventionnelles et qui n'ont pas d'explications. Lorsqu'il s'agit de constructions élémentaires la question « pourquoi ? » a rarement un intérêt outre linguistique.

Answer (score -1):

Ces propositions me semblent toutes correctes, et dépendre de ce qui est désigné ou sous-entendu.

- tiroir de droite -> non du buffet, mais tel qu'il est vu de face (c'est-à-dire son tiroir gauche, de son point de vue si j'ose dire ; mais pour un bureau, ce serait l'inverse).

1.1 Tu vois l'arbre, à droite ?

1.2 Le monument, à la droite de l'église, est la statue de X.

2.1 Le levier de cet appareil américain a trois positions: OFF sur gauche, AUTO au milieu, ON sur droite.

2.2 Vous voyez le paysage, derrière la Joconde, sur la droite du tableau ?

3.1 Le bateau donnait de la bande vers droite. [d'accord, on dit plutôt *tribord* en ce cas]

3.2 Dirige ta lunette vers la droite pour voir Altaïr.

Comment: Aucun de ces exemples ne correspond à un complément du nom comme dans celui fourni dans la question.

Comment: Le bateau donne de la bande *sur* tribord (ancien). Il a 5° de gite sur la droite